# Spring boot and react.js

Tags: javascript, eclipse, reactjs, spring-boot, react-native

I have a simple spring boot project which uses the frontend-maven-plugin for development of react js files.  It also includes webpack maven sure plugin execution. I can see that when I make changes to the app.js file that I have it correctly regenerates the bundle.js under static/built/bundles.js.  The server is meant to be listening on the static folder, as I am using liveReload, and any change to .css or html gets updated when i refresh the page.  However a ctrl + F5 doesnt update the javascript changes that are visible in bundle.js.

My app is basically the security app here with some changes -> https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/

What do I need to do to make sure it picks up the js changes without restarting the server?

I only have 4 gigs on my laptop, I can see that there is enough memory available, but the building is just going to 99% in eclipse and not finishing.  If i stop the listener for changes i.e. stop from command line npm(npm run-script watch )or webpacK the build finishes in eclipse.  IS there contention here/locking or is my laptop just not powerful enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a locking issue, webpack and node.js were running separately as processes, which i checked in Task Manager.  Once i removed the pom entry and stopped the Node.js processes running the issue was fixed.  Strange that an example on the internet doesn't mention this.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your changes that fixed this issue. I am working with Spring Security, Angular, VS Code and I would like the browser to reload when html and js files change. [https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/single](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/single)

Comment: Bit late but basically the two processes were trying to access the same resource and that was the problem.  I removed the process by commenting out the npm from pom and running it separately.  It manifested itself in a strange way if you want code i can supply it.